# Java Rounding to 15 decimal place

Tags: java, rounding, rounding-error

I have the below codes round the forward rate to 15 decimal place. When _ForwardRate is 13,555.0, the result return is wrong.

```
public double round(double Number, int Decimal_Place) {     
    if (Number==0) return 0;
    double _plug = 0.000001;
    if (Number < 0) {
        _plug = -0.000001;
    }
    //Sometime a number is rounded down to 2.22499999999 by java. 
    //Actual precision is 2.245.  Without this plug, a 2 dp rounding result
    //in 2.22 when it should be 2.23
    double _newNumber = Number;
    if (Decimal_Place==2) {
        _newNumber = _newNumber+_plug;      
    }

    double _number_abs = Math.abs(_newNumber);  
    double _factor = Math.pow(10, Decimal_Place);
    double _rd = Math.round(_number_abs * _factor);
    double _r = _rd/_factor;
    if (Number <= 0)
        _r = _r * -1;

    return _r;
}

Double _ForwardRate = getForward_rate();
BigDecimal _fwdrate_bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(_ForwardRate.doubleValue());
_ForwardRate = round(new Double(_fwdrate_bd.doubleValue()), 15);
```

**Current result**

```
9,223.372036854777
```

**Expected result**

```
13,555.000000000000000
```

Comment: What's the `round` function?

Comment: @AndrewL. I edited my post.

Comment: Something other than the rounding is wrong if you are expecting `13,555` compared to `9,223`

Comment: And, by the way, underscores aren't really encouraged in variable names in Java

Comment: I'd recommend following naming conventions for Java, such as camelCase and no underscores.

Comment: @AndrewL. Ok. Thanks for the reminder I will do that. :) Any idea of the cause of getting this unexpected result?

Comment: I'd like to say you are seeing this problem, based on the code comment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: This is all wrong.  Please study [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Can you explain exactly why you believe the result should be what you think it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that [`Math.round(double a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-) returns **`long`**, and you're *overflowing*.

One easy way to do this, is to use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

```
public static double round(double number, int decimalPlaces) {
    return BigDecimal.valueOf(number)
                     .setScale(decimalPlaces, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
                     .doubleValue();
}
```

This allows you to control the rounding mode. Note that the rounding done by `Math.round()` is a `HALF_CEILING` which isn't supported by [`setScale()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-java.math.RoundingMode-).

You might want to consider doing all you math using `BigDecimal`, if you need that level of precision.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
    double _number_abs = Math.abs(_newNumber);
```

At this point, `_number_abs` contains the value 13555.0

```
    double _factor = Math.pow(10, Decimal_Place);
```

Now `_factor` contains `1.0E15`

```
    double _rd = Math.round(_number_abs * _factor);
```

According to the Javadoc

> `Math.round()` Returns the closest long to the argument, with ties rounding to positive infinity.

Since `_number_abs * _factor` is `1.3555E19`, which is larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE`, the result is `Long.MAX_VALUE`, i.e. the "closest" `Long` to the given value.